# How to sort a query based on a hasmany value with containing search and pagination

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-8

I have an Event model which hasMany EventDate.
I'm running a query (for my livewire datatable) in which I fetch events with their media and eventdates. I limit the results based on if a year and/or a month is selected. There's also a text search. Finally I paginate the results.

This query and the filters are working fine. But I can't figure out how to sort the list of events based on the eventdates. I would like the result to list the eventdates descending. (this can be limited to the ->first() eventdate (in case there would be multiple)

How can I achieve this?

```
$events = Event::with('media', 'eventdates')->whereHas('eventdates', function (Builder $query) {

         $query
                    ->when($this->month > 0, function ($query) {

                        return $query
                            ->whereMonth('date', $this->month);

                    })
                    ->when($this->year > 0, function ($query) {

                         return $query
                             ->whereYear('date', $this->year);

                    });


    })->where('published', '1')->search($this->search)->paginate($this->perPage);
```

Comment: You need to run a relationship and raw query to do the order.

Comment: You may add my skype ID jesus.erwin.suarez143 I can mentor you.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer, in case it would be of use to anyone

```
$events = Event::select('events.*')
        ->join('event_dates', 'event_dates.event_id', '=', 'events.id')
        ->whereHas('eventdates', function (Builder $query) {

            $query
                ->when($this->month > 0, function ($query) {

                    return $query
                        ->whereMonth('date', $this->month);

                })
                ->when($this->year > 0, function ($query) {

                    return $query
                        ->whereYear('date', $this->year);

                });


        })
        ->where('published', '1')
        ->search($this->search)
        ->orderBy('event_dates.date', 'desc')
        ->paginate($this->perPage);
```